# How to get size of NATS Streaming Queue?

Tags: kubernetes, nats-streaming-server, openfaas

Background: I'm going to be doing some experiments with OpenFaaS (running in Kubernetes) where I will be invoking several asynchronous execution requests. OpenFaaS uses NATS Streaming to queue these requests for asynchronous function execution.

What I need is a way to determine the size of this NATS Streaming queue so I can know how many items are in the queue. Is there a command to get the size or number of items in a NATS Streaming Queue? I searched Google and the NATS documentation and found nothing of use.

I did find the command `kubectl logs deployment/queue-worker -n openfaas` from [here](https://github.com/openfaas/workshop/blob/master/lab7.md) which displays the logs of the queue; however, this is not quite what I want (I want the number of items left in the queue, not the queue's full logs).

Answer (score 2):

You can enable a [monitoring endpoint](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/nats_admin/monitoring) in NATS to get a number of general [endpoints](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/nats_admin/monitoring#monitoring-endpoints) to query which can go down to a specific channel.

You would then need to expose a Service for that endpoint in Kubernetes for external access, probably via an Ingress if you want more control over which endpoints and how they are exposed.

Have a look at the templates in a [nats-streaming-ft](https://github.com/canhnt/k8s-nats-streaming/blob/master/charts/nats-streaming-ft/templates/service.yaml) helm chart.

Add the monitoring port to your container `spec`

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nats-streaming
    args:
      - /opt/nats-streaming-server
      - --http_port=8222
```

And the chosen monitoring port to your `ports` list in the `Service`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nats-monitoring
  labels:
    app:  nats
spec:
  selector:
    app:  nats
  ports:
  - name: monitoring
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8222
```